# Differentiate the function $y=\cos^{-1}(\sin x)$ w.r.t $x$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

> Find $y'$ if $y=\cos^{-1}(\sin x)$

It is solved as
$$
y=\cos^{-1}(\cos(\pi/2-x))=\frac{\pi}{2}-x\\
y'=-1
$$

**My Attempt**

The function is defined for all real numbers.
$$
y'=\frac{-\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}=\frac{-\cos x}{\sqrt{\cos^2x}}=\frac{-\cos x}{|\cos x|}=\pm1
$$

Even in the first method isn't it the right way to solve 
$$
y=\cos^{-1}(\cos(\pi/2-x))=\frac{\pi}{2}-x\\\implies\cos y=\cos(\pi/2-x)\\
\implies y=2n\pi\pm\big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\big)\\
\implies y'=\pm1
$$

Is $y'=-1$ a complete solution ?

Comment: $\arccos(\sin(x))$ is evidently periodic and $\pi/2-x$ is not... as a start analyse in a fixed length of $2\pi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $\cos\mid_{[0,\pi]}:[0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ is bijective and has the inverse $\arccos:[-1,1]\to [0,\pi]$ and $\arccos(\cos(x))=x$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$ while $\cos(\arccos(y))=y$ for all $y\in[-1,1]$. Further $\cos\mid_{[0,\pi]}'(0)=\cos\mid_{[0,\pi]}'(\pi)=0$ and therefore $\arccos$ is just differentiable on $(-1,1)$.

Hence $\arccos(\cos(\frac{\pi}2-x))=\frac{\pi}2-x$ holds just if $\frac{\pi}2-x\in [0,\pi]$, so $x\in \left[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right]$.

That's why you should use the chain rule and note that $y$ is not differentiable if $\sin(x)=\pm1$ which is when $x=\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. Then, your computation are correct:
$$
y'=-\frac{\cos(x)}{|\cos(x)|}.
$$
But you can't just say $y'=\pm 1$. There is just one derivative and it depends on $x$.
$$
y'=-\frac{\cos(x)}{|\cos(x)|}=\begin{cases}
-1 & x\in \left(-\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\right)\\
1 & x\in \left(\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi,\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi\right)
\end{cases}
$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

---

If you plot the graph, then the result isn't even suprising:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odco70auib

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it $y'=\begin{cases}-1 \quad\text{if}\quad x\in(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})\\+1\quad \text{if}\quad \color{blue}{x\in(-2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2},-2k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2})}\end{cases}$ ?

Comment: Since $k$ is just some integer, the sign doesn't matter. The way I wrote, you get two intervals next to each other for a fixed $k$ while in your case the two intervals are farther to each other. But it is correct too.

Comment: ohh yup thats right. i didnt think that way.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\cos y=\sin x,$ and $0\le y\le\pi\ \ \ \ (1)$

$y=2k\pi\pm(\pi/2-x)$ where $k$ is an integer satisfying $(1)$

What if $0\le 2k\pi+\pi/2-x\le\pi,?\le x\le?$

Comment: thanks for ur hint. $\cos y=\cos(\pi/2-x)\implies y=2n\pi\pm (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$. $y\in[0,\pi]$, for $y=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $y'=-1$ for $0\leq 2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-x\leq\pi\implies 2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq 2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: but how can i derive it from $y'=\frac{-\cos x}{|\cos x|}=\begin{cases}-1\text{ if }\cos x>0\\+1\text{ if }\cos x<0\end{cases}$ ?

Comment: @ss1729, Observe  that $y' =-1$ in the first & fourth quadrants